# Upstart scripts causing problems

Tags: linux, script, boot, upstart

I like to start little web servers on boot. I've been using upstart, but often my scripts fail, causing important services like sshd to fail to start. What's a safer way to do this?

https://github.com/mcandre/node-ios7crypt/blob/66e79523d35f6bc6acc3e103bde6c56875430e70/upstart.conf

Answer (score 1):

According to #upstart, upstart scripts cannot interfere with other services such as sshd.

Apparently, my runlevels were wrong. I changed them to the following, and everything started working normally:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
```